# Push Notification GCM/APNS group "big view" only display 5 messages(then display xx new messages)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

I am looking to see how to make the "Big View" so that the push notifications group messages from 1 person together, and just display e.g. the latest 5, and show e.g. 9 new messages,Like on Whatsapp/Facebook messenger

How would i do that on "big view"? Any documentation that has guide for it? 
For both Android and IOS.

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are described in this guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Look for examples that use [`InboxStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html).